# Difference in Tense when using Spacy POS on the same sentence on different PCs

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I was taking a course on Udemy about NLP. So I reached the POS section. So when the instructor was demonstrating the POS tag attribute, I was having a difference in tense on the same sentence which we both were entering.

So I was using the sentence "I read books on SpaCy.". He was also using the same sentence but when we applied token.tag_ I got VBD where as he got VBP. Can anyone explain why it happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the models should be deterministic. It's possible that we missed something and that's not quite the case, but first you should check these things:

- are you using the same version of spaCy?
- are the models the same version? (small differences here would explain this)
- is the input string actually the same, or is it different? ("SpaCy" vs "spaCy" for example)
- is your code the same?

If everything is actually the same, what model are you using?

Comment: There is a difference in version. I am using SpaCy 3.0  whereas he was using some old one as the course is a bit old

Comment: Ah yeah, between 2 and 3 seeing differences is completely unsurprising, a lot changed.